# Conducting MLE for multivariate case (bivariate normal) in R

Tags: r, statistics, mle

The case is that I am trying to construct an MLE algortihm for a bivariate normal case. Yet, I stuck somewhere that seems there is no error, but when I run the script it ends up with a warning.

I have a sample of size n (a fixed constant, trained with 100, but can be anything else) from a bivariate normal distribution with mean `vector = (0,0)` and covariance `matrix = matrix(c(2.2,1.8,1.8,3),2,2)`

I've tried several optimization functions (including `nlm()`, `mle()`, `spg()` and `optim()`) to maximize the likelihood function (,or minimize neg-likelihood), but there are warnings or errors.

```
require(MASS)
require(tmvtnorm)
require(BB)
require(matrixcalc)
```

I've defined the first likelihood function as follows;

```
bvrt_ll = function(mu,sigma,rho,sample)
{
  n = nrow(sample)
  mu_hat = c(mu[1],mu[2])
  p = length(mu)
  if(sigma[1]>0 && sigma[2]>0)
  {
    if(rho<=1 && rho>=-1)
    {
    sigma_hat = matrix(c(sigma[1]^2
                     ,sigma[1]*sigma[2]*rho
                     ,sigma[1]*sigma[2]*rho
                     ,sigma[2]^2),2,2)
    stopifnot(is.positive.definite(sigma_hat))


    neg_likelihood = (n*p/2)*log(2*pi) + (n/2)*log(det(sigma_hat)) + 0.5*sum(((sample-mu_hat)%*%solve(sigma_hat)%*%t(sample-mu_hat)))

    return(neg_likelihood)
    }
  }
  else NA

}
```

I prefered this one since I could set the constraints for sigmas and rho, but when I use mle()

```
> mle(minuslogl = bvrt_ll  ,start = list(mu = mu_est,sigma=sigma_est,rho = 
rho_est)
+     ,method = "BFGS")
Error in optim(start, f, method = method, hessian = TRUE, ...) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

I also tried `nlm` and `spg` in package `BB`, but they did not help as well. I tried the same function without defining constraints (inside the likelihood, not in optimization function), I could have some results but with warnings, like in `nlm` and `spg` both said the process was failed due to covariance matrix being not positive definite while it was, I think that was due to iteration, when iterating covariance matrix might not have been positive definite, and the fact that I did not define the constraints.

Thus, as a result I need to construct an `mle` algorithm for bivariate normal, where do I do the mistake?

NOTE: I also tried the optimization functions with the following, (I am not sure I did it correct);

```
neg_likelihood = function(mu,sigma,rho)
{
    if(rho>=-1 && rho<=1)
        {
          -sum(mvtnorm::dmvnorm(x=sample_10,mean=mu
                    ,sigma = matrix(c(sigma[1]^2
                    ,sigma[1]*sigma[2]*rho,sigma[1]*sigma[2]*rho
                    ,sigma[2]^2),2,2),log = T))
        }
  else NA
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT : mu is a vector of length 2 specifying the population means, sigma is a vector of length 2 (specifying population standard deviations of the random variables), and rho is a scalar as correlation coefficient between the bivariate r.v s.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in closed form so there is no need for numeric optimization. See [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Estimation_of_parameters). Just use `colMeans` and `cov` and take note of the `method` argument in `help("cov")` and this comment

> The denominator `n - 1` is used which gives an unbiased estimator of the
>   (co)variance for i.i.d. observations. These functions return `NA` when
>   there is only one observation (whereas S-PLUS has been returning `NaN`),
>   and fail if `x` has length zero.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However, I want to show with iteration process that what you proposed is an MLE for covariance, actually. I need to do with number generation and optimization process to show that mle of covariance matrix and mu vector maximizes the likelihood function.

Comment: Even if you implement a Newton's method (say) it will converge in one iteration if you supply the analytical gradient and Hessian. You properly want another example. **If** you want to do this then anyway re-paramatize your parameters to use a e.g. a Cholesky decomposition for the co-variance matrix.

Comment: Exactly, but the thing is I could not set the constraints properly, so the R code runs with warnings or error. When I tried to set the constraint in the function with "if(rho>=-1 && rho<=1)", it didn't work. I want help only with constraints I guess, if I set the constraints properly, it would do it I think. The usage and examples lack explanation. Like, how to use constrOptim, spg, nlm or mle functions with proper constraints for this case, because I have multiple parameters.